# Need to create .tgz file in Windows

Tags: windows, tar, gzip

I need to create a .tgz file - NOT a tar.gz, a .tgz specifically - in Windows.

I've tried 7zip, Peazip, and ProgramArchiver, but they all create .tar.gz files. I've also tried running 7z from the command line, which just prompts an 'install 7zip' window (despite it already being installed). What can I do? Please help!

EDIT: I'm aware these files are functionally the same. The place I need to upload it to, however, will only accept a .tgz extension. I've tried uploading a .tar.gz and it will not take it! (Yes, it is stupid, yes, everyone using it knows it is stupid, but that's the way it is).

EDIT 2: Changing the extension worked! Thanks, folks... I guess I was too busy looking for the difficult answer of 'create it with .tgz' to think of the easy answer of 'create it as .tar.gz then change it' * facepalm*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534918/are-tar-gz-and-tgz-the-same-thing

Comment: What he/she/ultrasawblade said.  tar.gz is .tgz.  Create your tar.gz and rename. Unless .tgz is TRULY something else entirely, then you're on your own because we'd have no idea what it is.